# Use previous value of Pandas series with mix of strings and ints

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to overwrite the times with the date of that day.  This list is ~100 rows long, below is a sample:

```
    Date
0   May-21-20 #Gets passed
1   02:51PM #(should read May-21-20)
2   01:59PM #(should read May-21-20)
3   01:29PM #etc
4   12:45PM #etc
5   12:42PM
6   11:55AM
7   10:02AM
8   09:37AM #(should read May-21-20)
9   May-20-20 #gets passed
10  02:47PM #(should read May-20-20)
11  02:30PM #(should read May-20-20)
12  02:29PM #(should read May-20-20)
13  02:01PM #(should read May-20-20)
```

Here's where I'm currently at with my code:

```
for i in headline_table['Date']:
date_list = headline_table['Date'].tolist() #Make the pd Sereies a List
index_value = date_list.index(i) #Now a list so I can reference index value
previous = index_value - 1 #index of current minus one = previous value

if re.search(r'^[A-Z]', i):
    pass
else:
    headline_table['Date'][i] = headline_table.loc[previous, 'Date']
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to go about this but can't seem to figure it out.  I do not get any errors with the code, but the times do not get overwritten with the date, instead it seems nothing happens.

Comment: ```df.assign(dates = df.Date.str.extract("(\A[a-zA-Z].*)")).ffill().drop('Date',axis=1)``` ?

Answer (score 2):

We can do `where` with `ffill`

```
df['Date1']=df.Date.where(df.Date.str.contains('-')).ffill()
```